# autowired bean giving a nullpointer exception when used for global variable initialization

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've got a problem that seems very simple at the surface yet i can't seem to find a solution for it. I have a Service class called `SystemTasksService` that has two methods that are causing the problem, here is the code:

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public final class SystemTasksService {

    Map<String, String> getSeedRecordUnderReview(){
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    Map<String, String> getProduceTutorialUnderReview(){
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

}
```

And then these methodes are called in another class like so:

```
private Map<String, String> seedRecordUnderReview = systemTasksService.getSeedRecordUnderReview();

private Map<String, String> produceTutorialUnderReview = systemTasksService.getProduceTutorialUnderReview();
```

The systemTaskService is injected using the `@Autowired` annotation (its a spring boot app) and the problem doesn't lie here because i can call other methods on this service just fine (just not for initializing a global variable on the same line it is declared.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Regards,

Comment: You should post the error message

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: the error is nullpointer exception.. but nevermind i've already solved it. Will post the answer now

Comment: Is `systemTasksService` a variable name or a typo of the class name? If it's a variable, you need to show the initialization.

Comment: systemTasksService was an instance of the SystemTasksService autowired in a class called ModeratorService. But I solved my problem already :)

Comment: i see someone wants this thread closed, i'd like to keep it open so that others who may run into the same problem can benefit from the solution i've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that during object creation the autowired part comes after the initialization of the global variables, so when i'm calling the autowired systemListenerService before that it gives a nullpointer exception. I solve this problem by using the `@PostConstruct` annotation like so:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init(){
    seedRecordsUnderReview = systemTasksService.getSeedRecordsUnderReview();
    produceTutorialsUnderReview = systemTasksService.getProduceTutorialsUnderReview();
}
```

After the object has been constructed that SystemTaskService bean has been autowired and thus calling the methods on the systemTasksService instance no longer gives a nullpointer exception because the variable now references the autowired object.

Comment: Note that circumstances like this are exactly why it is recommended to use constructor injection and not field injection.